# Error while loading crystal report form in winforms

Tags: winforms, crystal-reports

hi programmers!
                   I deployed my project of winforms.It goes fine but while loading the form which contains crystals reports gives error like

[image]

I installed crystal report 9.0 but it still gives error.It occurs when i used this on another computer.
 Any solutions .Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it looks like you need the CR2008 runtime available: http://wiki.sdn.sap.com/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=56787567

- CRRedist2008_ia64.msi (64 bit Itanium)
- CRRedist2008_x64.msi (64 bit Intel)
- CRRedist2008_x86.msi (BootStrapper)

You can tell from the version number in the error message: 10.5.3700.0